# I'm unable to delete (or modify) .vbs files

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, vbscript

I've made different .vbs files but I can't delete or make any changes to them, I just get a message:

> You require permission from DOMAIN\user to make changes to this file

Where user is **my** own user.

#### What I've tried:

- Starting in Safe Mode
- Using Unlocker
- Changing the files Security permissions - (I even gave *Full Control* to *Everyone*)
  *Deleting through CMD as admin (Access is denied)

-Windows 7 Ultimate

---

I tried this on a bunch of computers and was successfully able to "change" (delete, move, rename etc.) all the files, just not on this computer.

---

Edit:
Results of running `icalcs myfile.vbs`

```
myfile.vbs NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
           DOMAIN\myuser:(I)(F)
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: Look for Local/Group Policy objects blocking access to VBS. Often done to mitigate Office/VBS Trojans; may be causing your problem.  Check "Computer Configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Software Restriction Policies" for one.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No Software Restriction Policies Defined

Comment: Can you copy the file to the same directory using a different extension, then delete the copy? E.g. `copy myfile.vbs myfile.txt` then delete the .txt file

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes.

Comment: Then it's not a permission issue. Run [Procmon](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) and filter it to only watch for operations on your .VBS file, then try to delete it and see what's causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run cmd as administrator
2. Delete the files using the del command

If you need more simple steps, then just enable the administrator account, and then use that account to log in. Browse to the files you want to delete, and do it. Instructions on enabling administrator account are here: http://www.intowindows.com/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-in-windows-10/

EDIT: If none of these work, try booting into another OS (e.g. from Linux, either from hard drive or portable USB) and deleting the files there

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: @WELZ updated mine (I know it's hard, but it's all I got)

Comment: My next plan was to do something similar to that, I was looking for a way to avoid it... to delete it (semi) traditionally.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the built-in Administrator account to delete a file owned by a user and to which they have full control. It would be better to explain *why* the OP cannot delete a file he has full control over and offer a solution that addresses that specific problem.